# Change the site's subtitle

Tags: bug, status-completed

When a question is migrated away from biology.stackexchange.com, the following is shown:

[image: Example migration message]

The subtitle of the site (currently “active researchers, academics, and students”) should be changed to something specific to biology so that the migration message makes more sense. After all, this is not StackExchange's only site for active researchers, academics, and students. For instance, it could be “biology researchers, academics, and students.”

Answer (score 1):

The description shown will now specify `biology`.